# SQL Combining MAX and SUM

Tags: sql, sql-server, sum, subquery, greatest-n-per-group

So I have one SQL table that contains the below columns:

```
License# - int
Name - char(255)
ActivityDate - datetime
FundsIn - money,null
```

There are ~2800 unique License numbers and will have numerous FundsIn each day. I am trying to find the last date there was activity (ActivityDate) and the sum of all of the FundsIn on that MAX ActivityDate.

Below is a query I've been trying to modify to get it to work, but it is returning the sum of the license number across all dates and not just the MAX date.

```
Select License, Name, MAX(ActivityDate), FundsIn
From (
    Select License, Name, ActivityDate, SUM(FundsIn) as Funds_In
    From Table1
    group by License, Name, ActivityDate
) foo
group by License, Name, FundsIn
```

I know the issue with the current query is that it is grouping the entire dataset of FundsIn, but I can't figure out how to limit the sum of FundsIn to only the MAX date. Any help would be appreciated.

Sample Date

```
License   Name   ActivityDate   FundsIn
123       A      8/29/2020      40
123       A      8/29/2020      60
123       A      8/29/2020      80
123       A      8/29/2020      55
123       A      8/30/2020      10
123       A      8/30/2020      15
123       A      8/30/2020      12
123       A      8/30/2020      60
123       A      8/30/2020      70
234       B      8/29/2020      12
234       B      8/29/2020      15
234       B      8/29/2020      19
234       B      8/29/2020      22
234       B      8/29/2020      33
234       B      8/30/2020      13
234       B      8/30/2020      78
234       B      8/30/2020      28
234       B      8/30/2020      34
234       B      8/30/2020      46
```

In the above data the query would return the below

```
License   Name   ActivityDate   FundsIn
123       A      8/30/2020      167
234       B      8/30/2020      199
```

Comment: Please show us sample data and desired results. As of now, there is more than one way to interpret your question.

Comment: I think you should show some data. But without testing, I think just having a ``max`` in your ``select`` wont make it. You should put ``MAX(ActivityDate)`` after the ``group by`` in a ``having`` command

Comment: You describe the correct order, but your code is the wrong way round. You should first calculate the max activity date, then join that (together with `name` and `license`) back to `Table1`. You'll have only the most recent records left. Then you can take the sum of the funds.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I understand that you want the sum of the funds on the latest activity date *per license* (not all licenses might be active every day).

There are multiple ways to phrase this. One method is a filter with a correlated subquery:

```
select license, name, activityDate, sum(fundsIn) fundsIn
from mytable t
where t.activityDate = (select max(t1.activityDate) from mytable t1 where t1.license = t.license)
group by license, name, activityDate
```

Out of other options, a more exotic alternative is `order by` and `top (1) with ties`:

```
select top (1) with ties license, name, activityDate, sum(fundsIn) fundsIn
from mytable t
group by license, name, activityDate
order by row_number() over(partition by license order by activityDate desc)
```

I would expect the second method to be less efficient on a large dataset.

Comment: That appears to be what I am looking for! Thank you! I modified slightly to exclude last activity date where FundsIn = 0. It seems to be working as expected. Would my added where clause cause any issues? Running fine now. Thanks again!
'''
Select License, Name, ActivityDate, SUM(FundsIN) as FundsIn
From table t
where t.ActivityDate = (
Select max(t1.activityDate) from table t1 where t1.License = t.License
and t1.FundsIn > 0)
group by License, Name, ActivityDate
order by ActivityDate desc, FundsIn desc, License
'''

Answer (score 1):

I think you're looking for somthing like this.  The CTE use row_number to find the maximum ActivityDate  per License.  Then the CTE is joined back to Table1 on License and ActivityDate (max.).

```
;with max_cte as (
    select *, row_number() over (partition by License order by activityDate desc) rn from Table1 t)
Select License, Name, ActivityDate, SUM(FundsIn) as Funds_In
From max_cte mc
     join Table1 t on mc.License=t.License
                      and mc.ActivityDate=t.ActvityDate
where mc.rn=1
group by License, Name, ActivityDate;
```

Comment: This seems to only pull the last activity date in the entire dataset, not the last activity date for each individual license.

Comment: It's updated now.  The max ActivityDate is per License now